# Building a Current Category-Focused Navigation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bigcommerce

I would like to develop a similar navigation to this website: http://www.enjukuracing.com/categories/nissan

They are on the BigCommerce platform and I like how their side navigation displays the categories and subcategories. Essentially I would like to know the logic in displaying something like this as well as what components in BigCommerce I would need to do this.

I’d like to point out a few things about this example that aren’t ideal to what we want.

- This site seems to be suffering from multiple locations of the same link (if you
  look at the source, one link appears 4 times - my site is trying to avoid this because of upwards of 800+ internal links and also because of site load times to generate the navigation)
- Each subcategory is generated for all the categories and different menu appearances—this is why they appear 4 times each

So ultimately, we’d want a navigation that does these things:

- Know what category we are currently in
- Display parent categories leading up to current category
- Display sibling categories to current category
- Display subcategory/children categories to current category
- Expand down upon click to display children categories

I know the Category API can tell me the hierarchy of the categories, but I feel making AJAX calls to a PHP file on each page of my website might be counter-intuitive to making my website more speedy. Is there any simple object that I can access with JS that I can manipulate on a page-level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did something like this using JS to figure out what categories to show/hide and which to have open/closed. First, include the category tree in your sidebar and hide it.

```
    function formatCustomSideBar(){
        var cats = [];
        $("ul.breadcrumbs > li").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("is-active")){
                var name = $(this).find("span").text();
                cats.push(name);
            } else {
                var name = $(this).find("a").text();
                cats.push(name);
            }
        });
        console.log(cats);

        $(".custom-nav li a").each(function(){
            var subCat = $(this).text();
            if( $.inArray(subCat, cats) !== -1 ){
                $(this).parent("li").addClass("active-category");
            }
        });
    };
    formatCustomSideBar();
```

Next, add all breadcrumb values into an array because the breadcrumb always tells us where we are on the site. Then loop the navigation tree, and add a class of `active-category` to the list item if it is present in the breadcrumb array. Using the `active-category` class and CSS, you can style the feature.

To add the toggling functionality, I would add an additional few lines to the end of my function to loop list items with the `active-category` class, and check if they have a child `<ul>` to find out if they have children categories, and add a class like `has-children` from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "include the category tree in your sidebar" - does this mean just call "%%SNIPPET_SideCategoryList%%" or "%%PANEL_SideCategoryList%%" and where do I place this?

Comment: I would use "%%PANEL_SideCategor‌​yList%%" to pull in the category tree. Place this wherever you'd like to include this dynamic sidebar list. In your example, it is in the sidebar which in most Blueprint themes for the cat page is found in the category.html file. Look for <div class="Left" id="LayoutColumn1"> area which is the left sidebar and add your code. Keep in mind my JS was written for Stencil, so you'll need to adjust class/element names for your blueprint theme.

Comment: I made some tweaks and I got the base functionality working-- thank you. Any suggestions if categories have the same name? I need to compare each breadcrumb and form a path almost.. For example, if I have two "Red" categories, say "Tops > Shirts > Red" and "Bottoms > Pants > Red", both "Red" categories are displayed.

Comment: I would use CSS to only show the ".active-category" <li> if it's parent has the class ".active-category" as well, or is directly under the <ul>. This would prevent the "Bottoms > Pants > Red" from showing if "Bottoms" and "Pants" didn't have the ".active-category" class.